# Open Source Cron Job Monitoring Webservice as Alternative to healthchecks.io

Tags: open-source, monitoring, web-services, system-monitor

I'm looking for a slim open source alternative to [healthchecks.io](https://healthchecks.io/) for self hosting.

It seems to be very simple to code for a basic function, but I had no luck to find a minimal solution.

The minimal solution should provide a simple client or a command line script, which sends a ping message to the CGI script on the server.
The message includes a long secret to identify plus an identifier for the service to track.
The CGI stores a timestamp to the database, if  credentials match.
Optionally the tool can create a nice plot, but this can also be performed by external tools.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW Healthchecks itself is open-source (BSD license) and can be self-hosted. It can use SQLite as the database backend. It does not need Redis, Celery, Memcache, Clickhouse or any major dependencies like that.

Source: https://github.com/healthchecks/healthchecks

For the client, a good option is [runitor](https://github.com/bdd/runitor). You can also [use curl](https://healthchecks.io/docs/bash/), which may already be installed.